Limit when a revisioned field can be synced from the policy level to the acount (PolicyCenter)
In PolicyCenter v10 on-premise, I have this situation with a field (let's call it FieldA) on PolicyContactRole which is revisioned and account syncable.

A user starts a PolicyChange with an effective date of today or in the past (not a future dated change).
The user changes FieldA  from "Alpha" to "Beta" in the PolicyChange transaction and saves a draft of the transaction
FieldA is synced to the Account level field and now reflects the value of "Beta"
The user decides to discard the PolicyChange and expects the Account level value of FieldA to be "Alpha" because they discarded the PolicyChange, but the Account level value of FieldA remains "Beta"

The business would like the field on the account to only be updated if the PolicyChange is bound and I so far have found no way to prevent the Account level field from being updated when a draft PolicyChange is saved.
Does anyone know if there is a way to only allow updates to the account level field if the policy transaction is bound?
I have looked at all the documentation around this and in the AccountContactRoleToPolicyContactRoleSyncedField.gs or PolicyNamedInsuredAccountSyncableImpl.gs classes and I find no place where I could reasonably expect to be able to limit the syncing of the field to only when the PolicyChange is bound.

The code in gsrc/gw/api/domain/account/AbstractAccountSyncableImpl.gs controls the general orchestration of account syncables across the policy transaction lifecycle.  In your question you say the sync happens when the draft is saved, but I believe it's more correct to say it happens when the transaction is quoted.  You can override/edit the implementation of the prepareForQuoteImpl() method to not sync at all, or only under certain circumstances.
Customers who I've worked with who have made these type of changes have, in some cases, reverted those changes because the overall change in behavior wasn't workable for them.  The issue you're flagging - that "what if" changes get sync'd to the account - is a known issue.
The better way to handle this is to NOT ALLOW users to overtype a contact or address.  That way it doesn't overwrite the Account-level information.  Address changes should ALWAYS be done by creating a new address and referencing that new address where appropriate.  Contact changes (ie name, other sync'd fields) should ONLY be done if they are business-relevant (ie name change on marriage/divorce).

Thanks Marty. That is really helpful. The behavior they have where the field "syncs" on the draft saving is because they also sync to a 3rd field that is not revisioned, which I just figured out today. Thanks for the sage advice Marty.

In PolicyCenter, managing account-field syncing based on the transaction state (like bound vs. draft) can get tricky because out-of-the-box sync mechanisms don’t usually differentiate between draft and bound states when syncing revisioned fields. You’re right that the standard AccountContactRoleToPolicyContactRoleSyncedField.gs or PolicyNamedInsuredAccountSyncableImpl.gs won't handle that conditional behavior out of the box.
For this, you'd want to customize the sync logic by creating a wrapper or interceptor around the syncing process. A practical way to do this is by customizing the AccountContactRole or PolicyContactRole object to check the transaction’s status before allowing the sync operation to proceed. Specifically, you could override or add a conditional check within the AccountContactRole object or introduce a helper method to assess if the transaction is bound before syncing any account-level changes.
Here’s how it might go: In your custom code, define a check within PolicyChange transactions, maybe a beforeSave() method or similar. If the transaction isn't in a bound state, throw a flag that prevents the sync to the account. Then, once the policy is bound, you’d allow the sync to go through. This prevents syncing during the draft stage and only commits changes to the account when the policy change is finalized.
If this workaround isn’t flexible enough, you may need to look into handling the logic within a custom plugin or using a field-level event handler for FieldA itself to track and control sync behavior based on the transaction lifecycle state directly.

Definitely helpful. I'll take a look at how much custom coding I would need to add to get this to work. In general, though, I usually go back to the business when the solution would require a lot of custom code that Guidewire might mark as technical debt.
